# Github markdown anchor link with #

Tags: github, markdown

I'm trying to update a README.md file on Github with an entry about C#. I've read numerous posts on how to make in text anchors using markdown. To be clear I have managed to make a link that works just writing Csharp, but I'd very much like to make it work with the hash symbol as well.

So basically I have a table of contents where I want to add C# and link to a point in the text further down with the same name:

```
## Table of Contents

- [C#](#c#)
```

(This does not make C# clickable)

And then further down:

```
## C#

- [Channel9](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/CSharp-Fundamentals-for-Absolute-Beginners)
```

I've tried adding forward slash before the hash in both the table of contents and in the main text (i.e. #c/#). Doesn't work. The only way I seem to get the table of contents to make a link out of c# is by doing this (but then it doesn't link to anywhere)

```
- [C#](c/#)
```

Sorry this must be a really basic issue but I can't seem to find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work if you just remove the trailing `#` on the link. It probably can't use the `#` and just stops at the `c`.

```
## Table of Contents

- [C#](#c)
```

```
# C#

- [Channel9](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/CSharp-Fundamentals-for-Absolute-Beginners)
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. Didn't think of just removing the trailing hash in the () altogether. Guess I thought it was necessary to match the text in the () and the text in the body.